# Can an RCL circuit be asymptotically unstable? If so, what does that mean physically?

Tags: circuit-analysis, control, kirchhoffs-laws, stability

I'm analyzing the asymptotic stability of the system of ODEs that comes from an RCL circuit in series. Below is my circuit, with battery voltage \$u(t)\$, resistor with constant \$R>0\$, capacitor with constant \$c>0\$, and inductor with constant \$L = 1\$.

```
  --> R>0 --->
 |           |
(u(t))      c>0
 |           |
  <-- L=1 <---
```

My understanding is this must behave the order 2 non-homogeneous linear system:
$$u(t) = R i(t) + i'(t) + (1/c)\int_0^t i(\tau)d\tau$$

Letting $$x_1(t) = i(t),\text{   } x_2(t) = \int_0^t i(\tau) d\tau$$,  we have
$$x' = Ax + Bu$$  where

$$A = \left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
-R  & -1/c \\ 
1 & 0
\end{matrix} \right]$$

Hence, the solution space is $$\{ce^{At}x_0 + x_p(t) \}$$, where $$x_p$$ is the particular solution needed to satisfy the inhomogeneity of the equation (the $$u(t)$$), and $$ce^{At}x_0$$ is the general solution.

This means we are asymptotically stable if and only if \$\sigma(A)\$ lies in the left half plane. Note that for the matrix above,
$$\sigma(A) = \{s: \det(sI-A) = s^2+Rs +1/c = 0\} = \{-R \pm R\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{R^2}(\frac{1}{c}-\alpha) } \}$$

If we let the capacitor constant $$c = \infty$$, then we have

$$A = \left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
-R  & 0 \\ 
1 & 0
\end{matrix} 
\right]$$

(for some reason, that won't render as a 2x2 matrix, but it should be 2x2)
and
$$\sigma(A) = \{s: det(sI-A) = s^2+Rs = 0\} = \{-R, 0\}$$. Hence, this should be an asymptotically unstable system.

Yet, when $$c = \infty$$, I think the circuit diagram is identical except with no capacitor. If this is the case, our differential equation is   $$V = R i(t) + i'(t)$$, with solution space
$$\{i_0 e^{-Rt} + i_p(t)\}$$. This is asymptotically stable!

Can you help me reconcile these two interpretations? The first seems to imply that asymptotic instability can happen, but I don't know what it means physically. The second seems to imply that it cannot happen physically.

Comment: A pure RLC circuit can never be unstable.